# How to animate a spinner while performing a workload via threading

Tags: ios, sql, multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am having troubles using multiple threads in my Delphi xe5 application for an iOS device. My goal is to perform 'some work' (SQL query), while having a TAniIndicator is spinning. I have tried using Applicaiton.ProcessMessages(), but that doesn't keep the spinner loading smoothly, if spinning at all sometimes.

Here is my current code for a btn.OnClick

```
begin
  if btnLogin.Text = 'Login' then begin
    aThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
    aThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    aThread.Start;
      while Mode1 = 0 do begin
          Form_Login.LoadSpinnerFrame.visible := True;
          Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Visible := True;
          Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Enabled := True;
         // Application.ProcessMessages;
       end;
    Form_Login.LoadSpinnerFrame.visible := False;
    Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Visible := False;
    Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Enabled := False;
    btnLogin.Text := 'Logout';
    aThread.Destroy;
  end else begin
    btnLogin.Text := 'Login';
  end;
```

Here is code for the thread.execute method

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Form_login.mode1 := 0;
    Sleep(5000);
  Form_login.mode1 := 1;
end;
```

I am at a point where I can consistently get the Thread to execute, but the spinner never shows. 
How Can I perform 'some work', while a spinner is animating during the work load?

Thank you,
Using Delphi xe5 for developing an iOS application.

UPDATED:
Okay, so updated using the code below from LU RD... It works, however, I've noticed added lag. When ran under the debugger, the application hangs between the lines:

```
Thread.DoTerminate;
Thread.FFinished := True;
```

under the ThreadProc Function of System.Classes Unit

Any clue as to why ? Or what I can do to prevent that added 5 second lag? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable your spinner before starting the thread.

Define an `OnTerminate` method for your thread where you disable the spinner.

Do your work in the thread and when it is ready, the `OnTerminate` takes care of removing the spinner.

Note: There is no need to explicitly free your thread, since `FreeOnTerminate` is true.

```
begin
  if btnLogin.Text = 'Login' then begin
    Form_Login.LoadSpinnerFrame.visible := True;
    Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Visible := True;
    Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Enabled := True;
    btnLogin.Enabled := False;
    aThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
    aThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    aThread.OnTerminate := Self.WorkIsDone;
    aThread.Start;
  end 
  else begin
    btnLogin.Text := 'Login';
  end; 

procedure TYourForm.WorkIsDone(Sender : TObject);
begin
  Form_Login.LoadSpinnerFrame.visible := False;
  Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Visible := False;
  Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Enabled := False;
  btnLogin.Text := 'Logout';
  btnLogin.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  // Make your work
end;
```

The important thing here is that the program flow is event driven. No polling required which can drain the CPU cycles and make the GUI unresponsive.

Comment: Works Wonderfully. Thanks for the quick response !

Comment: I have noticed something though. @Lu RD, please review the revised edit to the question for possible assistance please !

Comment: `DoTerminate` is the point where the `OnTerminate` method is called. I can't tell if this is related to the debugging process or the FMX framework. It is not related to any code shown here. I suggest you make a new question, and provide a minimal compilable example where this problem is shown. The question you originally asked here is answered.

Comment: Be aware that there is a bug in XE5 that causes threads to hang in the OnTerminate code if a spinner is active. It only affects iOS. The Quality Central number is QC#117582. I don't know of any workaround other than not showing the spinner.

Comment: @norgepaul, I can't find that QC report.