# How to get rid of lag when working with multi threading

Tags: ios, multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

Refer to: [How to animate a spinner while performing a workload via threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141869/how-to-animate-a-spinner-while-performing-a-workload-via-threading)

I am working with a Delphi xe5 Application for iOS. While performing a SQL query, I have a TAniIndicator spinning. I am using threads - for specific code, see article stated above.

Everything works, however, when using the code I was helped with in the previous question, I've noticed added lag. When ran under the debugger, the application hangs between the lines:

```
Thread.DoTerminate;
Thread.FFinished := True;
```

under the ThreadProc Function of System.Classes Unit

Any clue as to why ? Or what I can do to prevent that added 5 second lag? Thank you

Update reply to TLama:

```
procedure TForm_Login.WorkIsDone(Sender : TObject);
begin
  Form_Login.LoadSpinnerFrame.visible := False;
  Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Visible := False;
  Form_Login.LoadSpinner.Enabled := False;
  Form_Login.btnLogin.Text := 'Logout';
  Form_Login.btnLogin.Enabled := True;
  if GoodLogin = 1 then
    Main_Form.show;
end;
```

My onTerminate() is linked to the above procedure.

Comment: Do you have any code in the `OnTerminate` event method of your thread ?

Comment: Question Updated, Thank you

Comment: You sure you took out that `Sleep(5000)`?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: the `Sleep()` was in the thread's `Execute()` method, not in its `OnTerminate` event handler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I saw that, but who knows where the OP put it while testing/debugging.

Comment: yes @Marcus, that was the first thing I checked.. lol

Comment: Is the lag same if `GoodLogin` is 1 and <> 1?

Comment: Yes, and the 5 seconds is more like... 30 seconds too..

Comment: @norgepaul says there is a "known" bug in the spinner in XE5 for iOS. It has to do with the spinner being active when a `OnTerminate` call is made. QC is #117572. There is also #118973.

Comment: QC #118973 is just a duplicate of #117572.

Comment: So the best thing to do is to emulate a spinning component, at least until this bug is fixed. It could probably be done with a timer and an image with alternating icons.

Comment: Found this component in the FMX library, [`FMX.Ani.TBitmapListAnimation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Ani.TBitmapListAnimation). Seems to do the animation nicely.

Comment: Seems to b independent of TAniIndicator. I still experience a lag time even when using a TBitmapListAnimation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TThread.DoTerminate()` calls `TThread.Synchronize()` to fire the `TThread.OnTerminate` event handler in the main thread. `TThread` is then blocked until the main thread processes that request - which does not happen instantaneously as the main thread has to detect and process new messages first - and the `OnTerminate` handler exits.  Only then is control returned to `TThread` so it can finish its logic.  So if you are encountering a 5s lag in `DoTerminate()`, then it mean the main thread is taking 5s to detect and process the `Synchronize()` request.

Comment: So is there anything I can do about that, or no ?

Comment: For other answer-seekers regarding this question. Review comments above in replies to the OP